# How to add a ListItem into a list while iterating (C#)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono, thread-safety, gtk

I have a small application that using BackgroundWorker to process the `IEnumerator<T> list` at all time.

The code basically like this:

```
while(true){
    foreach(T item in list){
       // Process each item and send process
       // Add an object in child List ( List<T1> item.Result )
    }
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

Now I have a button and a textbox, which will add directly to the IEnumerator.

The problem is that after I add button, the backgroundworker continue to process it's currently processing Item, but will stop after finish that item. It does not continue.

How can I safely add an Item to the list without affect the backgroundworker? Beside the background worker also do adding objects to the item. What should be the solution for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have the background worker iterate over a copy of the original list, not the list itself.

```
 while (true)
 {
       foreach (T item in new List<T>( list ))
       {
          ....
       }
       Thread.Sleep(500);
 }
```

If you attempt to modify a collection while enumerating over it, the enumerator will throw an exception.  From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx):

> An enumerator remains valid as long as the collection remains
>   unchanged. If changes are made to the collection, such as adding,
>   modifying, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably
>   invalidated and the next call to MoveNext or Reset throws an
>   InvalidOperationException. If the collection is modified between
>   MoveNext and Current, Current returns the element that it is set to,
>   even if the enumerator is already invalidated.

Comment: Yes, but I do not modify the enumerator. The one i am editing is the item.Result. Which is not affect the itemList. If I make a copy of this. item.Result will not be modified.

Comment: @Duc - the copy of the list will contain references to the same objects as the original so if you modify the object in the copy, you're modifying the copy in the original (assuming T isn't a value type).  You asked about adding to the list while iterating, which would modify the underlying collection for the enumerator and will invalid it, causing it to throw an exception on the next move.

Answer (score 2):

You should learn the basics about multi-threaded programming first, so, here it goes.

Try something along this:

```
// shared queue
ConcurrentQueue<T> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<T>();
// shared wait handle
AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent();
```

The queue is better here than the list, because it allows you to add and remove elements from it without worrying about the index of the current element - you just `Enqueue()` items on the other and, and `Dequeue()` them on the other. Use a class from `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace, which handles thread-safe access for you automatically (and, due to complicated reasons you might want to read on later, is faster than a simple `lock()`).

Now, the foreground thread:

```
// schedule the work
queue.Enqueue(itemOfWork);
// and wake up our worker
autoEvent.Set();
```

The sprinkly-magical part here is the `Set()` invoked on our `WaitHandle` (yes, `AutoResetEvent` is an implementation of a `WaitHandle`). It wakes up a single thread that has been waiting for the synchronization event to fire, without using such ugly constructs as `Thread.Sleep()`. A call to `Sleep()` is almost always a sign of a mistake in multithreaded code!

Ok, for the last part - worker thread. Not many changes here:

```
while(true)
{
  // wait for the signal
  autoEvent.WaitOne();
  T item;
  // grab the work item
  queue.TryDequeue(out item);

  // handle the item here;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use the "lock" keyword to prevent simultaniously accessing the shared "list" variable from both places of code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I just put a lock. But the program will let the user wait until all items are finish enumerate before add it to the list. It works, but basically it's not really ideal for user experience. :)